# Can death create a loophole for two exact duplicate people existing in the same universe?

Tags: alternate-history, alternate-reality, spacetime-dimensions, alternate-earth, philosophy

Here'a another one of my weird questions...

So there's two universes, two of many in a many worlds/multiverse scenario. We'll call one Universe A and the other Universe B for sanity's sake. And there are two people, the exact same guy, but one from each universe, so Guy A and Guy B.

Hand wave how Guy A would "travel" into Universe B for now. Since two of the same thing can't occupy the same place and time because they would annihilate each other (Guy A and Guy B would blow up upon contact (that's a sci-fi assumption so forgive me if that's way off). Would it make a difference if Guy B in Universe B was already dead before Guy A appeared in Universe B?

If Guy B is already dead wouldn't everything about him be so completely different from Guy A that Guy A could then inhabit his space in Universe B?

Comment: "that's a sci-fi assumption" - that's only an assumption. As far as traveling between universes is only hypothetical, you are free to make your own assumptions.

Comment: So this is one of those "whatever you want the answer to be is the answer" questions.  You've written 8 sentences, and I count 4 assumptions which don't have to be true, you just assigned them to be true.  The most interesting, to me, is the [Twin Earth Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_Earth_thought_experiment) where you have to be *very very very* precise as to what it means for "Guy A and Guy B to be the exact same guy."

Comment: That assumption was a Timecop plot point, I've not seen it anywhere else.

Comment: Guy A and Guy B cannot be the same guy because, if Guy B is dead, Guy A must also be dead (regardless of which universes they might be in). In any case, Guy B (dead or not) will occupy space in his universe which is not  available for anything else to occupy. If, on the other hand, you are trying to confuse Death then you might succeed, but that is an entirely different kind of story.

Comment: The thing is "hand waving". If you do this at the beginning why bother with anything else later or? It is what you want it to be. They are not the same person.

Comment: You might want to take out your Playstation and chuck in the Chronocross CD when you have time to spare.

Comment: Not at all an answer to your question but this sets the stage for a very interesting story where guy A and guy B both try to swap universes at the same time (they're the same person so they have to, by principle). They get in the machine turn it on and switch but no one believes them because while the universe is different to them, to the rest universe nothing has changed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Two of the same thing can't occupy the same place and time because**
>   **they would annihilate each other.**

Two of anything can't occupy the same place and time.  My teeth moving into the space of this delicious chicken move the chicken molecules aside.

If you propose Guy A and Guy B can't exist in the same universe, or that Guy A and Guy B will blow up if they touch, you need to assign some special properties of matter which gets preposterous for the "2 versions cant touch" scenario.  I would like to think Guy A can feast on the delicious chicken (they have Popeye's!) in Universe B. Those B chicken molecules are incorporated into the pectorals of Guy A who is still doing his push-ups while visiting universe B.  Guy B was eating this same chicken earlier in the day and is made in part of B chicken molecules from the day before.  Molecules is molecules.

You could make A molecules incompatible with B molecules in which case Guy A will die immediately on visiting Universe B.  There is not a way I can imagine such that Guy B turns his B chicken molecules into Guy B molecules to which Guy A and only Guy A is allergic.  They are just molecules.  They come and go.

If Guy A can breathe B air and eat B chicken he can handle B molecules, and he can shake hands with Guy B who is made of those molecules.

And maybe more?  Maybe they will fall in love?  I bet they have a lot in common.

Comment: Whew, I'm glad this is the case since Popeyes chicken is the shiznit! Thank you.

Comment: Wasn't there this movie about guy traveling in time seducing himself as a women because later in time he change his gender giving birth to himself as a man who later became the bomber he timetravel after?

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY your stock went up again with me - that is a fantastic story and takes the multiple selves thing as far as it can go.  I know I read it recently?  I am sure the good people of fiction stack will know if someone else doesn't visit here and link it up.

Comment: @Willk found it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film) with Ethan Hawke

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Predestination starring Ethan Hawke. very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Theres another theory that states our universe is in fact infinite itself. Infinity is a lot, and this means that every possible event allowed by physics has already happened an infinite amount of times, is already happening an infinite amount of times, and will continue to happen an infinite amount of times. This means infinite copies of you identical in every way to you exist, have always existed, and will always exist. You just need to travel in a straight line for an infinite distance with an infinite amount of time and eventually (were talking so many years and light years traveled that this computer couldnt remember all the zeros) youd bump into a perfect copy of your starting point complete with a perfect copy of yourself.

Theres no magic hand wavey quantum "not magic" way to make this happen instantly though. Its also just a theory. We dont actually know how big our universe is because we can only observe as far as electromagnetic radiation will travel. Maybe it ends only a few light years past that, or maybe it goes on forever. Maybe the universe infinite and theres infinite iterations of it. We just really dont know, but yeah. Thats the only somewhat scientifically supported way to meet your alternate you. Travel an infinite distance for an infinite amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Death doesn't create a loophole. As long as the two Guys don't occupy the same time and place they can both exist in the same universe. In this scenario, one of them is dead and his exact duplicate is wandering around alive.

This isn't a problem. It's simply another case of the querent overthinking the situation and believing there's a problem when there's not. Rest easy.

Death doesn't create the loophole, it's old fashioned differences in spatio-temporal locations.